# Using kinect with OpenNi

Tags: opencv, kinect, point-cloud-library

I am newbie to kinect and openNi. But according to some old tutorials I have tried installing kinect sensor(primeSensor) and OpenNi for object detection with kinect. But as OpenNi project is closed now, I am not able to find alternatives to OpenNi, I also tried pcl libraries, but I was stuck there as I couldn't run any project because of: '**Entry point is not found error**'. 
I need to use kinect for object detection with windows 7 32 bit. I wanted to use pcl libraries with openNi. 
Can anyone please guide me what should I do? Or it'll be really grateful if anyone could tell me from where should I start. Please give me some new tutorials for using kinect.

Answer (score 0):

I use kinect 2.0, pcl and OpenCV in VS2012, OpenNI is no longer supported and I suggest you grab Kinect frame by this(it works fine):http://unanancyowen.com/?p=1232